# Delphi 2010 " is" statement behaves differently than Delphi 7's?

Tags: delphi

Why does the code below return TRUE in Delphi 7 and FALSE in Delphi 2010?  TBitBtn is a descendant of TButton.

```
    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
      public
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TestControl( aControl: TControl);
    begin
      if (aControl is TButton) then showmessage('TRUE') else showmessage('FALSE');
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      TestControl(BitBtn1);
    end;
```

Comment: Is `TBitBtn` really the only class you tested before concluding that `is` is the thing that's different?

Comment: Just a very minor small little tiny detail but did you know there is a BoolToStr function (I didn't until recently)

Comment: Thanks, Remko.  I was looking for that just the other day, but didn't find it. Glad you mentioned it! - but it just returns the integer representation. I know there's one that returns a string ("True" or "False") but haven't been able to remember where it is!

Comment: use BoolToStr(SomeBoolean, True), the 2nd parameter is UseBoolStr ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`is` did not change. [`TBitBtn` is a subtype of `TCustomButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Buttons.TBitBtn), not `TButton`, as you state.

Comment: Yes, and that did change, I think between D2007 and D2009

Comment: That's it! Thanks, Craig. I got stung by going back to Delphi 7's help to check it's ancestor! It never occurred to me to check in D2010's help (which I try to avoid when I can...) Thanks, Craig and I voted you, Jason, up too!

SO rocks!

Comment: Tom, the help is never the place I look for stuff like that. I always consult the source code directly. Ctrl+click on the `TBitBtn` identifier to be taken to its declaration.

Comment: This topic was covered last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946316/what-happened-to-codegears-tbitbtn-and-tbutton-inheritence-chain